# In Darktable, how do I know which images have been edited (have settings)?

Tags: photo-editing, darktable

I'm exploring Darktable and find it excellent.

However, after I make changes in the Darktable editor, when I switch back to Lighttable, how can I determine which images have already been edited? There doesn't appear to be any indicator on the thumbnail to show that I have edited it.

This is quite frustrating and I hope there is a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Changed photos have a tag `darktable|changed` applied to them, which you can use for filtering in the collect images module. This feature has been [introduced in darktable 0.9](https://www.darktable.org/2011/06/released-0-9/).

Also you see a icon on the top right of each picture in the lighttable: [image]

Comment: @benrudgers I did :) Tough I called it module, not panel. Do you know the correct term?

Answer (score 1):

sebix is correct. You may also add multiple filters to sort through your images in lighttable under the collect images module like shown in this snapshot:

[image]

https://www.flickr.com/photos/44333999@N04/36246239492/in/dateposted/

You can see I'm searching only one day of photos of images at 100 ISO that have been changed/edited.

Comment: Excellent answers. Thank you very much. This indeed will allow for a smooth workflow

Comment: Is there a way to sort all of the images in a folder so the changed images (edited images) appear together and the unchanged image thumbnails follow afterwards? 

This would allow me to see quickly in a folder which images are finished, and to select other images to edit from the list of thumbnails.